# How to replace Android's Download Manager by an other default app?

Tags: stock-android, downloading, default-applications, download-manager

I got enough of the poor functionality of *com.android.providers.downloads*

So I decided for a better [alternative download manger](https://alternativeto.net/software/advanced-download-manager/?platform=android).

But how can I choose the alternative as preferred download manager? My alternative download manager is listening to my clipboard. But this does not help me, because not all addresses to online files can be easily copied into Android's clipboard.

Comment: The Android Downloadmanager is a system app and can't be replaced by a regular app. My be with root permissions it may be possible to do so.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to have Android version above 5.1 and familiar with command line interfaces, then you could use termux. It has a built in binary wget to basically download anything. Just put `wget https://whateverlink.exe` and it will start downloading it. All you'll be needing is the link to download the file you want to download. The built in download manager being a system app, is actually a system wide download manager for all the gui interfaces on the device. If you happen to have root privilege, and try doing `pm -k uninstall 0 com.android.providers.download` and `pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.android.providers.download.ui`(you can also do this with `adb`). What this will do is, uninstall download manager, but will be availbale like before if phone is disabled, (also if you like to play it safe and have root, better to perform `pm disable com.android.providers.download`, in this way you can enable it anytime with `pm enable com.android.providers.download`).Now with uninstalled/disabled, if you try downloading something on your browser, you'll see that download fails. Even with a third party download manager, because everything downloadable on gui apps uses the built in Download manager. However, termux uses binaries `wget` to download stuffs, hence doesn't need a download manager becuase it has its own libraries and binaries writen to download. Yep, there you go. You can find termux on Google Play Store. To download `wget`, just type in `pkg install wget` on the command line, and it'll download wget for you. From then on you could use `wget https://pastelinktodownload` to download. Although termux is way more than just a simple download manager. Enjoy! Hope this helps (:

Comment: Thank you. Too complicated, though

Comment: Trust me its not. Download termux. Type `pkg install wget`, it'll install wget. Then change directory to your sdcard by typing `cd /sdcard/`. And then grab any download link, and to download just type `wget downloadlink` and it'll start downloading (:

Comment: You dont need to do `pkg install wget` the second time you start downloading something. (:

Answer (score 0):

you can use your alternative download manager to select which storage should be used and you can't change download process to the alternate.